# Awkward white space above outputed Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I outputed the data from my database in a HTML Table and styled it with CSS. Everything is fine, but there is an awkward White space above the outputed Table. (see picture). What's wrong with my code?

Result:
[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Create new user</title>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "users";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "select * from employee";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 echo "<table>";
 echo "<th>Identifier</th><th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["vorname"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["nachname"] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</br>";
 
    }
 
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "</table>";

$conn->close();

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result : no white space above the Table

Many Thanks

Comment: `<div stlye="vertical-align:top">` maybe?

Comment: Open `Inspect Element` and see what is there?

Comment: Also remove this space (between php start tag and your first variable).

Comment: Not related to your question, but your code can be improved to ease the maintenance. Start with a [DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613030/do-i-need-a-doctype-declaration-in-a-php-file-with-html). Also try not to mix presentation with code. Your PHP presentation logic (the HTML output) is only expecting an array. Make your array aviable before starting the HTML. Then you can simply your PHP presentation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you adding a `<br>`

```
echo "</br>";
```

in your while loop.

Try this -

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["vorname"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["nachname"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

If this does not fix, try inspecting and see what is adding space. Also check for the padding and margins in the computed view in chrome inspect view.

If nothing works, try setting `top:0` for the div and may be for table :)

Comment: Yes it did the trick! it was indeed the </br> Tag, it was inside the loop! But again, it should'nt make w white space above the table! awkward! but thanks, it worked!